# How come func is called from a function?

Tags: javascript

```
function negate(func) {
  return function(x) {
    return !func(x);
  };
}
var isNotNaN = negate(isNaN);
show(isNotNaN(NaN));
```

This is from a javascript book I'm reading. `func` is used as a function with the argument `x` and the negate sign preceding it. How come?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: ever heard of recursion ?

Comment: Why not? Can you pinpoint more precisely what you find so disturbing about this code? :)

Comment: @Satya: There is no recursion here.

Comment: `how come?` i guess ... well ... not sure, probably ... here's the answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript . And in other words: `this is how it was made`.

Comment: The "negate" function is a function that takes another function as an argument. Is that part clear?

Answer (score 5):

The `negate` function accepts a function as an argument and returns a new function it creates that, when called, will call the original function with the argument you give it, negate that function's return value, and return that negated value.

`negate` is used to create a function we assign to `isNotNaN` that, when called, will call `isNaN` with whatever argument you pass it and negate the result.

So when you call `isNotNaN` with `NaN`, `isNotNaN` calls `isNaN(NaN)`, which returns `true`. `isNotNaN` then negates that, getting `false`, and returns that value.

Comment: Is there any benefit of doing so or is it simply fooling around?

Comment: @Amberlamps: Creating a function that transforms the result of another function can be very useful.

Comment: Okay, generally speaking, but I meant in that very certain case.

Comment: @Amberlamps: I think the book is probably trying to use a simple example to discuss closures. I probably wouldn't have used `NaN` in any example intended to be simple. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Man I'm learning javascript for the first time and the book throws me off a lot. Well, thank goodness for Stack Overflow

Comment: @user2668069: I'm glad that helped! You may want a different book. Which book is it?

Answer (score 0):

Using functions that work on functions is a concept that everyone struggles with at first, so don't beat yourself up. But once grokked, it can be a incredibly powerful tool.

One of the staples of functional programming, that is also valid in JavaScript, is that functions are no different from other primitives, like numbers. They are, in layman's terms, things you can do stuff with. Numbers can be added, subtracted, negated, and functions can be applied, combined, convoluted.

So we can have a function called `add` that will add two numbers, and we can have a function `combine` that combines two functions, like this:

```
//add is a function with two parameters that are numbers
//add's result is a number    
var add = function (first, second){
   var result = first + second
   return result;
}

//combine is a function with two parameters that are functions with one parameter
//combine's result is a function with one parameter
var combine = function (first, second){
  var result = function(x) { return first(second(x)); }
  return result;
}
```

As you can see, these two methods are more or less identical in structure. They will be called like this:

```
add(1, 2); //result is 3

var double = function (x) {return x*2};
var square = function (x) {return x*x};

// result is a function that returns a double of the square
var squareAndDouble = combine(double, square);

squareAndDouble(3); //result is 18
```

---

So now, let's deconstruct your example:

```
function negate(func) {
   return function(x) {
     return !func(x);
   };
}
```

This is a function called `negate` that takes a parameter called `func`. `func` is a function of one parameter and it's result is a boolean. That's needed in order for `func(x)` to be a legal expression, and why `!func(x)` is legal.

In the body of `negate` a new function is constructed. This function does not have a name, nor does it need one, because we are constructing and returning it. Whoever calls the `negate` function should take care of the naming (I'll call it the result function). Essentially, this is an equivalent form of the `negate` function, one that I personally prefer in my code:

```
function negate(func) {
   var result = function(x) {
     return !func(x);
   };
   return result;
}
```

The result function will take a single parameter called `x`, and it will return the value of the `!func(x)` expression, essentially negating the value returned from `func`, i.e. if `func(x)` returns a truthy value, the result will be false, and vice versa.

That is why, when we call the `negate` function, providing it with the `[isNaN][1]` function (that does indeed take a single parameter, and returns a boolean value), we get back a function that does the opposite of `isNaN`. That (nameless) function is accommodated in the `isNotNaN` variable.

Now, since that variable holds a function, we can execute is just like a normal function, and `isNotNaN(NaN))` will return `false`.

```
isNotNan(Nan) => !isNaN(NaN) => !true => false
```